# No puedo mover este contenedor

Tags: html5, css3

Quiero mover el contenedor purpura de modo que quede arriba del formulario:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
como esta imagen [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

puedo hacerlo usando transform pero no se si es buena practica. Lo he intentado
con las propiedades de flex pero nada... Desde ya muchas gracias.
html5 code : https://pastebin.pl/view/30ba172f
css3 code : https://pastebin.pl/view/0de8ca39

Comment: Agrega aquí tu código por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Bueno realmente para que se vea como lo quieres sería hacer 2 cosas muy sencillas.*

**1.** *agregar un div que contenga tus etiquetas del lado derecho, es decir un div que contenga al div con clase try y al div con clase form.*
**2.** *a tu clase try le quitas el width: 25%, ya que dicho elemento va a ocupar el mismo tamaño que el formulario y le agregas un margin-bottom para que de el espacio entre ambos elementos.*

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-image: url(./images/bg-intro-desktop.png);
  background-color: hsl(0, 100%, 74%);
}

.dad {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 50px 50px;
}

.text-content {
  margin: 150px 10px;
  color: white;
}

.form {
  display: block;
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  background: white;
}

.form-inside>input {
  margin: 5px auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 450px;
  height: 50px;
}

.form-inside {
  margin: 20px;
  /* background: white;*/
}

.try {
  height: 50px;
  justify-self: flex-start;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: hsl(248, 32%, 49%);
  margin-bottom: .9rem;
}

.try>p {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.button {
  color: white;
  background: hsl(154, 59%, 51%);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.attribution {
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
}

.attribution a {
  color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="dad">
    <div class="text-content">
      <h1>Learn to code <br> by watching others</h1>

      <p> See how experienced developers solve problems in real-time. <br> Watching scripted tutorials is great, but understanding how <br> developers think is invaluable. </p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <div class="try">
        <p> <span> Try it free 7 days </span> then $20/mo. thereafter</p>
      </div>
      <div class="form">
        <div class="form-inside">
          <input type="text" placeholder="First Name"> <br>

          <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name"> <br>

          <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address"> <br>

          <input type="password" placeholder="Password"> <br>

          <input type="button" class="button" value="Claim your free trial"> <br>

          <p class="terms"> By clicking the button, you are agreeing to our Terms and Services </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <footer>
    <p class="attribution">
      Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>. Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>.
    </p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

*Ya que tienes tu hoja de estilos, he movido tu código css que tienes al inicio de tu html a dicha hoja.*

*Saludos*